# Save an enum class variable into JSON

Tags: c++, json, qt, serialization, enums

I want to save some info in the JSON format.
Consider following code snippet. I have an error in the `save()` method where a variable of type `enum class` assigned as `QJsonValue`.

How can I use `enum class` in this situation?
Thank you

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    enum class Status { Undefined, S1, S2 };
    Q_ENUM(Status)

    explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void save(QString filename) {
        //...
        QJsonObject jsonObj;
        jsonObj["id"] = m_id;
        jsonObj["status"] = m_status;   //<-- Error: no known conversion from 'MyClass::Status' to 'const QJsonValue' for 1st argument
        //...

        //Save QJsonDocument into target file
    }

private:
    QString m_id;
    MyClass::Status m_status;
    //...
};
```

**Note:** If I change `enum class` to old `enum`, this code will work fine. But with `enum class` it will not be compiled.

**More Info:** See `JSON Save Game Example` in Qt source. It has a class named `Character` and it has an traditional `enum` named `ClassType`. Try to change `enum` to `enum class`. It will not works. How to make it working?

Comment: With `enum`, variables can be converted into `int`. But with `enum class`, it's not clear how it should be converted -- a string? number? some class? Please elaborate on this.

Comment: Perhaps `enum class` is not the right tool for the job. If you have an `enum` which you specifically want converted to an `int`, then simply using `enum` would be just fine. Otherwise you'd probably need to provide a way to convert your `enum class` into int / string / double etc

Comment: `enum class` is a new approach and great replacement for traditional `enum` so it is preferred to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

> There are no implicit conversions from the values of a scoped enumerator to integral types, although static_cast may be used to obtain the numeric value of the enumerator.

So this should work:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    enum class Status { Undefined, S1, S2 };
    Q_ENUM(Status)

    explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void save(QString filename) {
        //...
        QJsonObject jsonObj;
        jsonObj["id"] = m_id;
        jsonObj["status"] = static_cast<int>(m_status);   //<-- Error: no known conversion from 'MyClass::Status' to 'const QJsonValue' for 1st argument
        //...

        //Save QJsonDocument into target file
    }

private:
    QString m_id;
    MyClass::Status m_status;
    //...
};
```

Comment: This way is more general and seems to be more performant

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your `enum class` to a `QVariant` and assign it to `QJsonValue` :

```
jsonObj["status"] = QVariant::fromValue(m_status).toJsonValue();
```